# IE issue - jQuery .change() is not triggering callback when using checkbox/radio button?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a form with multiple inputs, either radio or checkboxes. Upon clicking specific checkbox/radio button, it will trigger the "checked" of other certain checkbox/radio button. It seems that on IE 8-10, the .change()'s callback only happen when the input element LOSES focus.

How can I make it trigger the callback as soon as change is detected?

Maybe I'm making mistake with my JS method:

```
$(function() {
    $("#table_id input").change(function() {
        // do w/e stuff
        if (this_guy_is_checked) {
            check_this_other_guy();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use the click binding rather than the change binding.. change is not registered until the element loses focus.

Comment: Seems fine in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ep8ng/

Comment: @ArunPJohny i dont have ie9 on my laptop, im sure that when i tested on ie8-10, it did not change until the element lost focus =/

Comment: can you check the attached fiddle... whether anything is printed in the browser console

Comment: @Robert the click() seems to do the trick. i will test more tomorrow.

Comment: @Robert you should write the answer so he can mark it and this won't be on unanswered page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the click binding rather then the change binding.. change is not registered until the element loses focus. (in IE)

```
$(element).click(function(){
   //do something
});
```